# How to specify what website urls can use your Google API number

Tags: google-cloud-platform, maps

I suddenly had a surge in hits on my maps and was charged for it for the first time ever. I am concerned that some other website is using my API.

Is there a way in the Google Cloud console or platform to specify which websites can use your Google Map API?

Answer (score 0):

As a Best Practices you need to use API Key, you need to get the API key see below steps:

**1** - Go to the Google Cloud Platform Console.

**2** - From the Project drop-down menu, select or create the project for which you want to add an API key.

**3** - From the Navigation menu, select **APIs & Services > Credentials**.

**4** - On the **Credentials** page, click **Create credentials > API key**.

- The **API key created** dialog displays your newly created API key.

**5** - On the dialog, click **Restrict Key**.

**6** - On the **API key** page, under **Key restrictions**, **set the Application restrictions**.

- Select **HTTP referrers (web sites)**.
- Add the referrers (follow the instructions).
- Click **Save**.

Then [Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey) as well some details on how to restrict an API key